# How much non-continuous time can I spend in Canada as a US citizen?

Tags: canada

I am US citizen, I have a full time employment as a software engineer which allows me to work from anywhere, although I have to go on site once every 2 months. I have met a girl in Canada and we want to spend a lot of time with each other, she cant come to the US due to work/School.

I would like go stay in Canada for 1 to 2 months at a time, come back to the US for about 2-3 weeks for work/errands/etc, then go back to Canada again for another month or two, and repeat.

I know that I'm allowed to spend 6 months in Canada, but at some point are they going to have an issue with me visiting so often and staying for an extended amount of time?

Comment: @chx while it seems it may be acceptable for immigration, the tax authorities may nonetheless require payment of income tax since this pattern results in staying will over half the time in Canada.

Comment: Sure. That's possible. That question belongs to expats though :)